# NullPointerException while using elastic search 5.5 Bulk Ingest API with Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-kafka

Getting NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequest.validate(BulkRequest.java:604)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.TransportActionNodeProxy.execute(TransportActionNodeProxy.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.lambda$execute$0(TransportProxyClient.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:250)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:363)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:408)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:54)
```

I have a scenario where multiple concurrent tasks are running in 4 executors in Spark Streaming Application and each of them reads data from Kafka, prepare the bulk and ingest the batch of records in ES index. I'm getting this weird NullPointerException with some of those batch of records for the first time but they are getting processed successfully in the second run.

Can someone please advise why this is happening.

Comment: Have you considered just using Kafka Connect (which is part of Apache Kafka) to stream the data from Kafka to Elasticsearch? Check it out: https://speakerdeck.com/rmoff/building-streaming-data-pipelines-with-elasticsearch-apache-kafka-and-ksql

Comment: As of now we are using Spark Kafka Streaming as part of our current tool stack. But this is really coll stuff which you have shared, will take a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is the code snippet I am using first line is the dependency from my build.sbt file

```
//lib dependency in build.sbt
"org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark-20" % "5.6.5"

//below is the connection variables required by Spark

val resources: String =
  s"${appConf.getString("es-index")}/${appConf.getString("es.type")}"
val esConfig: Map[String, String] = Map(
  "es.index.auto.create" -> s"${appConf.getString("es.index.auto.create")}",
  "es.nodes" -> s"${appConf.getString("es-nodes")}",
  "es.port" -> s"${appConf.getInt("es.port")}",
  "es.nodes.wan.only" -> s"${appConf.getString("es.nodes.wan.only")}",
  "es.net.ssl" -> s"${appConf.getString("es.net.ssl")}"
)

import org.elasticsearch.spark._
    val dstream: InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] =
  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    ssc,
    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
    ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](conn.topic,
                                                 conn.kafkaProps)
  )
dstream.foreachRDD(rdd =>
  rdd.map(_.value).saveJsonToEs(resources,esConfig))
ssc.checkpoint("/tmp/OACSpark")
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

**I have used typesafe config to read config from a properties file.**
**I was publishing data in the form of json to kafka so I used the "saveJsonToEs()" api, you can find more on the connectors' documentation on Elasticsearch's website"**

Comment: Thanks @Yayati... but as of now we are not using Spark ES connector. Please let me know if there is a way to do it via ES JAVA API which we are currently using.

Comment: Hi Shobhit. The ES-Spark Connector uses ES Java Connector under the hood. I believe you would be fine.

Comment: Hey Yayati.. we are planning to move on to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround as of now to push the records at a time to ES index and removed this bulk API (bulk API also does the same thing behind the scene).